# Does Lebesgue Change of Variables only hold for Borel functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In Bogachev, *Measure Theorem*, Theorem 3.7.1 states:

If $F : \mathbb{R}^n \supseteq U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ and injective, then for any $A \subseteq U$ Lebesgue measurable and any Borel function $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, on has the equality:
$\int_A g(F(x)) |JF(x)|dx = \int_{F(A)} g(y) dy$, where $JF(x)$ is the Jacobian determinant of $F$ at $x$.

I am wondering about if/how this can be extended to Lebesgue functions $g$. Since if $g$ is Lebesgue, $g=h$ $\lambda$ a.e. for some $h$ Borel, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, we would like to be able to just put $h$ in for $g$ and show that the equality holds for all Lebesgue measurable functions.

This may not work though: $g=h$ $\lambda$ a.e. doesn't clearly imply $g \circ F = h \circ F$, in fact for $F$ a constant function one can easily find $g,h$ s.t. $g=h$ a.e. but $g\circ F(x) \neq h \circ F(x)$ for all $x$. But we have the condition that $F$ is injective and $C^1$. In this circumstance can we prove that $g \circ F = h \circ F$ a.e. (I'm assuming not, otherwise the theorem would have been stated to include Lebesgue measurable functions). If not, what is a counterexample? Does this provide a counterexample to the above theorem but for Lebesgue measurable functions?

Note that for $F$ a diffeomorphism onto its image, we have a well defined $F^{-1}$, which is $C^1$ by the inverse function theorem, hence locally Lipschitz. Locally Lipschitz functions preserve null sets, hence $F \circ g = F \circ h$ $\lambda$ a.e. provided $g=h$ $\lambda$ a.e. I am looking for a strengthening of this result.

Comment: I've seen the theorem stated for $g$ Lebesgue integrable as well (currently in the process of learning it myself so I can't comment too much on your approach).

Comment: If $N=\{x\colon g(x)\neq h(x)\}$, then $N$ is null by hypothesis. Now, $\{x\colon (g\circ F)(x)\neq (h\circ F)(x)\}=\{x\colon F(x)\in N\}=F^{-1}(N)$ should be null since $F^{-1}$ is $C^1$, hence locally Lipschitz.

Comment: @Thorgott $JF(x)$ could $=0$. Thus inverse function theorem doesn't necessarily apply.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Are you sure it's not in the case that $F$ is a diffeomorphism, this is how the theorem is given in Folland, Real Analysis. In this case, as is noted at the end of my post, the theorem holds for Lebesgue functions.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Maybe this can be fixed with an appeal to Sard's theorem. It may also be worthwhile to check how much the proof in Bogachev breaks down with weakened hypothesis and whether it can just be adapted. I'll think about this again tomorrow.

Comment: @Thorgott The proof breaks down as I detailed somewhat above. The issue is the we can prove the result for indicator functions of Borel sets (it is very important these set are Borel as we prove it for closed cubes and then for open sets and are able to argue that it works for all Borel sets since the open sets are a $\pi$-system generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). We can use the indicator function result to go to all functions using standard monotone/dominated convergence arguments. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) For the proof to go through in the Lebesgue measurable case, it seems we need either 1) to show it for Lebesgue indicator functions and got to Lebesgue function from there in the standard way or 2) to show it works up to a.e. equivalence. Since I cannot find anyone who states the theorem for Lebesgue functions, I think it probably doesn't hold. So really I'm looking for the counterexample. In this case we need a 1-1 $C^1$ function $F$ s.t. $JF(x) =0$ at some point and s.t. for some null $N$, $F^{-1}(N)$ is not null. Sard's theorem seems relevant in this case.

Comment: By the way, the book I'm using as reference is Herbert Amann, Joachim Escher's Analysis III. In the text, the theorem is proven when $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, but in the exercises, they ask to prove the following (I modified notation): Let $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be open, and $F: U \to \Bbb{R}^n$ be $C^1$, and define $C := \{x \in U| \, J_F(x) = 0\}$. Suppose that the restriction of $F$ to $U \setminus C$ is injective. Let $g: F[U] \to E$ be a function ($E$ is a Banach space). Then, $g$ is Lebesgue-integrable if and only if $g \circ F \cdot |J_F(\cdot)|$ is Lebesgue integrable

Comment: and in this case, we have the formula $\int_{F(U)}g(y) \, dy = \int_U g(F(x)) \cdot |J_F(x)|\, dx$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the reference. I put together a proof of the exercise below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was giving me so much trouble, but looking at the theorem statement given by peek-a-boo motivated the following proof.

Note: In the following we use the notation $JF(x)$ to represent the Jacobian determinant of $F$ at $x$ (not the derivative) and use $|JF(x)|$ to be the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant.

Note, we are assuming the following:

Theorem: Suppose $F: \mathbb{R}^n \supseteq U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism onto its image. Then for any $g$ Lebesgue measurable, $g(F(x)) |JF(x)| \in L^1(A) \iff g \in L^1(F(A))$ and $\int_A g(F(x)) |JF(x)|dx = \int_{F(A)} g(y) dy$ whenever $g \in L^+(F(A))$ or $g \in L^1(F(A))$.

For the above, a proof can be seen in Folland, *Real Analysis*, Theorem 2.47. Now we have the following result.

Theorem: Suppose $F: \mathbb{R}^n \supseteq U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ and let $C := JF^{-1}(0)$. Suppose that $F|_{U-C}$ is injective. Then for any $g$ Lebesgue measurable, $g(F(x)) |JF(x)| \in L^1(A) \iff g \in L^1(F(A))$ and $\int_A g(F(x)) |JF(x)|dx = \int_{F(A)} g(y) dy$ whenever $g \in L^+(F(A))$ or $g \in L^1(F(A))$.

Proof: Sard's theorem gives that $F(C) = 0$. Note also $JF$ is continuous, hence $C$ is closed and $U- C$ is open. Therefore the inverse function theorem gives that since $F|_{U-C}$ is injective, it is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

Now consider the case $g \in L^+(F(A))$. Then $$\int_A g(F(x))|JF(x)| dx = \int_{A - C} g(F(x))|JF(x)| dx + \int_{A \cap C} g(F(x))|JF(x)| dx = \int_{A - C} g(F(x))|JF(x)| dx,$$ since $JF|_C = 0$. Then $A - C \subseteq U - C$ and is Lebesgue measurable. On $U - C$, $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, thus we have that $\int_{A-C} g(F(x)) |JF(x)| dx = \int_{F(A - C)} g(y) dy$. Then $$\int_{F(A)} g(y) dy = \int_{F(A - C) \cup F(C)} g(y) dy \leq \int_{F(A-C)} g(y) dy + \int_{F(C)} g(y) dy = \int_{F(A-C)} g(y) dy,$$ since $m(F(C)) = 0$.  But also clearly, $\int_{F(A-C)} g(y) dy \leq \int_{F(A)} g(y) dy $, so we have equality. Thus $\int_A g(F(x)) |JF(x)| dx = \int_{F(A-C)} g(y) dy = \int_{F(A)} g(y) dy$.

Then by taking absolute values, we see that $g \in L^1(F(A)) \iff g(F(x)) |JF(x)| \in L^1(A)$. In the case that $g \in L^1(F(A))$, the same argument as above works, since we then have $g(F(x)) |JF(x)| \in L^1(A)$ and all the integrals then make sense.

Comment: I think you want to work with $|JF|$ instead of $JF$ when you define $C$ and in a couple places after. You can also cut the inequalities at the end: $F(A-C)$ and $F(C)$ are disjoint since $A-C$ and $C$ are disjoint + $F$ injective. Other than that, this looks good to me.

Comment: @Thorgott $F$ isn't necessarily injective on all of $U$ (or all of $A$), only on $U-C$. So maybe $F(A-C)$ could have nontrivial intersection with $F(C)$, but I can't think of an example where this could be the case and may never be the case, but at least that's not clear to me. Also $|JF|^{-1}(0) = JF^{-1}(0)$ so that shouldn't matter in defining $C$, anywhere else absolute value is missing around $JF$ is probably a mistake.

Comment: You're right, I had forgotten that you weakened the hypothesis of injectivity. Maybe the latter thing is a notation issue, but I understand $JF$ to be the Jacobian of $F$ and $|JF|$ to be the determinant thereof, in which case these preimages are different (they wouldn't even be preimages of the same $0$) and the distinction is necessary (you need $JF$ invertible, not just non-zero for the inverse function theorem).

Comment: @Thorgott Good point, I'll add I note.  I was thinking of $JF$ as determinant, $|JF|$ as the absolute value of the determinant (this distinction is important, we are using the absolute value of the determinant since measure theoretic integration is not oriented and so e.g. we want the integral of a non-negative function non-negative even after change of variable, which may have negative determinant.)